# Interlocked.Increment not thread safe?

Tags: c#, multithreading, interlocked

I found a compiler bug in just one line of code:

```
int thisIndex = Interlocked.Increment(ref messagesIndex) & indexMask;
```

The definitions are:

```
static int messagesIndex = -1;
public const int MaxMessages = 0x10000;
const int indexMask = MaxMessages-1;
```

`messagesIndex` is not accessed by any other line of code.

If I run that code billions of times in a single thread, I don't get any errors.

If I run the above line on several threads, I get the same number twice and another number gets skipped every 1x-thousand times.

The following line I have run billions of times on 6 threads without ever getting an error:

```
int thisIndex = Interlocked.Increment(ref messagesIndex);
```

**Conclusion and Question**

It seems that `Interlocked.Increment()` on its own works as expected, but `Interlocked.Increment()` & `indexMask` does not :-(

Any idea how I can make it work properly all the time, not just 99.99% ?

I tried to assign `Interlocked.Increment(ref messagesIndex)` to a volatile integer variable and do the `"& indexMask"` operation on that variable:

```
[ThreadStatic]
volatile static int nextIncrement;

nextIncrement = Interlocked.Increment(ref mainIndexIncrementModTest);
indexes[testThreadIndex++] = nextIncrement & maskIncrementModTest;
```

It causes the same problem like when I write it in 1 line.

**Disassembly**

Maybe someone can guess from the disassembly what problem the compiler introduces:

```
indexes[testThreadIndex++] = Interlocked.Increment(ref mainIndexIncrementTest);
0000009a  mov         eax, dword ptr [ebp-48h] 
0000009d  mov         dword ptr [ebp-58h], eax 
000000a0  inc         dword ptr [ebp-48h] 
000000a3  mov         eax, dword ptr [ebp-44h] 
000000a6  mov         dword ptr [ebp-5Ch], eax 
000000a9  lea         ecx, ds:[00198F84h] 
000000af  call        6D758403 
000000b4  mov         dword ptr [ebp-60h], eax 
000000b7  mov         eax, dword ptr [ebp-58h] 

000000ba  mov         edx, dword ptr [ebp-5Ch] 
000000bd  cmp         eax, dword ptr [edx+4] 
000000c0  jb          000000C7 
000000c2  call        6D9C2804 
000000c7  mov         ecx, dword ptr [ebp-60h] 
000000ca  mov         dword ptr [edx+eax*4+8], ecx 

indexes[testThreadIndex++] = Interlocked.Increment(ref mainIndexIncrementModTest) & maskIncrementModTest;
0000009a  mov         eax, dword ptr [ebp-48h] 
0000009d  mov         dword ptr [ebp-58h], eax 
000000a0  inc         dword ptr [ebp-48h] 
000000a3  mov         eax, dword ptr [ebp-44h] 
000000a6  mov         dword ptr [ebp-5Ch], eax 
000000a9  lea         ecx,ds:[001D8F88h] 
000000af  call        6D947C8B 
000000b4  mov         dword ptr [ebp-60h], eax 
000000b7  mov         eax, dword ptr [ebp-60h] 
000000ba  and         eax, 0FFFh 
000000bf  mov         edx, dword ptr [ebp-58h] 
000000c2  mov         ecx, dword ptr [ebp-5Ch] 
000000c5  cmp         edx, dword ptr [ecx+4] 
000000c8  jb          000000CF 
000000ca  call        6DBB208C 
000000cf  mov         dword ptr [ecx+edx*4+8], eax
```

**Bug Detection**

To discover the bug, I run the problem line in 6 threads endlessly and each thread writes the returned integers in huge integer arrays. After some time, I stop the threads and search all six integer arrays if every number is returned exactly once (of course, I allow for the "& indexMask" operation).

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;


namespace RealTimeTracer 
{
    class Test 
    {
        #region Test Increment Multi Threads
        //      ----------------------------

        const int maxThreadIndexIncrementTest = 0x200000;
        static int mainIndexIncrementTest = -1; //the counter gets incremented before its use
        static int[][] threadIndexThraces;

        private static void testIncrementMultiThread() 
        {
            const int maxTestThreads = 6;

            Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "MainThread";

            //start writer test threads
            Console.WriteLine("start " + maxTestThreads + " test writer threads.");
            Thread[] testThreads = testThreads = new Thread[maxTestThreads];
            threadIndexThraces = new int[maxTestThreads][];
            int testcycle = 0;

            do 
            {
                testcycle++;
                Console.WriteLine("testcycle " + testcycle);
                for (int testThreadIndex = 0; testThreadIndex < maxTestThreads; testThreadIndex++) 
                {
                    Thread testThread = new Thread(testIncrementThreadBody);
                    testThread.Name = "TestThread " + testThreadIndex;
                    testThreads[testThreadIndex] = testThread;
                    threadIndexThraces[testThreadIndex] = new int[maxThreadIndexIncrementTest+1]; //last int will be never used, but easier for programming
                }

                mainIndexIncrementTest = -1; //the counter gets incremented before its use
                for (int testThreadIndex = 0; testThreadIndex < maxTestThreads; testThreadIndex++) 
                {
                    testThreads[testThreadIndex].Start(testThreadIndex);
                }

                //wait for writer test threads
                Console.WriteLine("wait for writer threads.");

                foreach (Thread testThread in testThreads)
                {
                    testThread.Join();
                }

                //verify that EVERY index is used exactly by one thread.
                Console.WriteLine("Verify");
                int[] threadIndexes = new int[maxTestThreads];

                for (int counter = 0; counter < mainIndexIncrementTest; counter++) 
                {
                    int threadIndex = 0;
                    for (; threadIndex < maxTestThreads; threadIndex++) 
                    {
                        if (threadIndexThraces[threadIndex][threadIndexes[threadIndex]]==counter) 
                        {
                            threadIndexes[threadIndex]++;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (threadIndex==maxTestThreads) 
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Could not find index: " + counter);
                    }
                }
            } while (!Console.KeyAvailable);
        }

        public static void testIncrementThreadBody(object threadNoObject)
        {
            int threadNo = (int)threadNoObject;
            int[] indexes = threadIndexThraces[threadNo];
            int testThreadIndex = 0;
            try
            {
                for (int counter = 0; counter < maxThreadIndexIncrementTest; counter++)      
                {
                    indexes[testThreadIndex++] = Interlocked.Increment(ref mainIndexIncrementTest);
                }
            } 
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                OneTimeTracer.Trace(Thread.CurrentThread.Name + ex.Message);
            }
        }
        #endregion


        #region Test Increment Mod Multi Threads
        //      --------------------------------

        const int maxThreadIndexIncrementModTest = 0x200000;
        static int mainIndexIncrementModTest = -1; //the counter gets incremented before its use
        const int maxIncrementModTest = 0x1000;
        const int maskIncrementModTest = maxIncrementModTest - 1;


        private static void testIncrementModMultiThread() 
        {
            const int maxTestThreads = 6;

            Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "MainThread";

            //start writer test threads 
            Console.WriteLine("start " + maxTestThreads + " test writer threads.");
            Thread[] testThreads = testThreads = new Thread[maxTestThreads];
            threadIndexThraces = new int[maxTestThreads][];
            int testcycle = 0;
            do 
            {
                testcycle++;
                Console.WriteLine("testcycle " + testcycle);
                for (int testThreadIndex = 0; testThreadIndex < maxTestThreads; testThreadIndex++)
                {
                    Thread testThread = new Thread(testIncrementModThreadBody);
                    testThread.Name = "TestThread " + testThreadIndex;
                    testThreads[testThreadIndex] = testThread;
                    threadIndexThraces[testThreadIndex] = new int[maxThreadIndexIncrementModTest+1]; //last int will be never used, but easier for programming
                }

                mainIndexIncrementModTest = -1; //the counter gets incremented before its use
                for (int testThreadIndex = 0; testThreadIndex < maxTestThreads; testThreadIndex++) 
                {
                    testThreads[testThreadIndex].Start(testThreadIndex);
                }

                //wait for writer test threads
                Console.WriteLine("wait for writer threads.");
                foreach (Thread testThread in testThreads) 
                {
                    testThread.Join();
                }

                //verify that EVERY index is used exactly by one thread.
                Console.WriteLine("Verify");
                int[] threadIndexes = new int[maxTestThreads];
                int expectedIncrement = 0;
                for (int counter = 0; counter < mainIndexIncrementModTest; counter++) 
                {
                    int threadIndex = 0;
                    for (; threadIndex < maxTestThreads; threadIndex++) 
                    {
                        if (threadIndexes[threadIndex]<maxThreadIndexIncrementModTest     && 
threadIndexThraces[threadIndex][threadIndexes[threadIndex]]==expectedIncrement) 
                        {
                            threadIndexes[threadIndex]++;
                            expectedIncrement++;
                            if (expectedIncrement==maxIncrementModTest) 
                            {
                                expectedIncrement = 0;
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (threadIndex==maxTestThreads) 
                    {
                        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                        for (int threadErrorIndex = 0; threadErrorIndex < maxTestThreads; threadErrorIndex++)
                        {
                            int index = threadIndexes[threadErrorIndex];
                            if (index<0) 
                            {
                                stringBuilder.AppendLine("Thread " + threadErrorIndex + " is empty");
                            }
                            else if (index==0)
                            {
                                stringBuilder.AppendLine("Thread " + threadErrorIndex + "[0]=" +
                                threadIndexThraces[threadErrorIndex][0]);
                            }
                            else if (index>=maxThreadIndexIncrementModTest) 
                            {
                                stringBuilder.AppendLine("Thread " + threadErrorIndex + "[" + (index-1) + "]=" +
                threadIndexThraces[threadErrorIndex][maxThreadIndexIncrementModTest-2] + ", " + 
                threadIndexThraces[threadErrorIndex][maxThreadIndexIncrementModTest-1]);
                            } 
                            else 
                            {
                                stringBuilder.AppendLine("Thread " + threadErrorIndex + "[" + (index-1) + "]=" +
                threadIndexThraces[threadErrorIndex][index-1] + ", " + 
                threadIndexThraces[threadErrorIndex][index]);
                            }
                        } 

                        string exceptionString = "Could not find index: " + expectedIncrement + " for counter " + counter + Environment.NewLine + stringBuilder.ToString();
                        Console.WriteLine(exceptionString);

                        return;
                        //throw new Exception(exceptionString);
                    }
                }
            } while (!Console.KeyAvailable);
        }


        public static void testIncrementModThreadBody(object threadNoObject)
        {
            int threadNo = (int)threadNoObject;
            int[] indexes = threadIndexThraces[threadNo];
            int testThreadIndex = 0;
            try
            {
                for (int counter = 0; counter < maxThreadIndexIncrementModTest; counter++) 
                {
                    // indexes[testThreadIndex++] = Interlocked.Increment(ref mainIndexIncrementModTest) & maskIncrementModTest;
                    int nextIncrement = Interlocked.Increment(ref mainIndexIncrementModTest);
                    indexes[testThreadIndex++] = nextIncrement & maskIncrementModTest;
                }
            } 
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                OneTimeTracer.Trace(Thread.CurrentThread.Name + ex.Message);
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

This produces the following error:

Content of the 6 int-arrays (1 per thread)
    Thread 0[30851]=2637, 2641
    Thread 1[31214]=2639, 2644
    Thread 2[48244]=2638, 2643
    Thread 3[26512]=2635, 2642
    Thread 4[0]=**2636**, 2775
    Thread 5[9173]=2629, **2636**

Explanation:
    Thread 4 uses 2636
    Thread 5 also uses 2636 !!!! This should never happen
    Thread 0 used 2637
    Thread 2 used 2638
    Thread 1 used 2639
    2640 is not used by any thread !!! That's the error the test detects
    Thread 0 used 2641
    Thread 3 used 2642

Comment: The increment and `&` are two operations, there is no reason why the combination should be atomic. Use locks to address such a combination of operations.

Comment: Your question has received some close votes. Some feedback:

Keep it very targeted. Say: a) what you're trying to do, b) how you're doing it, c) what you expected, d) what actually happened.

If there's any chance you believe the problem is in your code, then focus on your code first. It's okay to include your speculations, but that should be left for the end so it doesn't distract from the issue.

If you believe there's an error with the CLR, then focus on that -- don't include something to test _your_ code -- include a method to test _CLR_ code, and the machine code it generates.

Comment: Candide's comment is wrong. Only Increment must be multithreading safe (atomic). Once Increment returns the correct value, any further operation on that value does not influence messagesIndex but a local value, which cannot be seen by the other threads.

Comment: Cory: your answer shows that you have not understood the problem I described nor tried the test code I provided. Please do not use your complete misunderstanding to state that the question should be closed. "My code" consists or exactly 1 line: "int thisIndex = Interlocked.Increment(ref messagesIndex) & indexMask;" Then I provide test code which proves that this statement sometimes produces the same number, which obviously never should happen. And no, the error does not occure when thisIndex returns to zero.

Comment: @Candide: Although you have got many upvotes atomicity plays no role here. See my answer.

Comment: Instead of changing this question, it is better to close it. It seems people did not understand what the problem is, meaning I have to rewrite the question completely, which would make some of the answers provided out of context. I would close the question myself, but I don't know how to do that. I hope rewriting everything from scratch and posting it as a new question is not against the rules.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is not Interlocked which is wrong. There is also no race condition. It does not even have something to do with multithreading.

- Interlocked.Increment(ref variable) & Mask

There is no race condition and no problem with atomicity as it was speculated. Interlocked returns the read value in a register (eax). The masking happens on the read value inside a register which has nothing to do with memory models or atomicity. Registers and local variables cannot be seen from other threads and hence not interfere.

- Testing

You are verifying that all values are seen by using a int[nThreads] where you check each thread if it has seen the value at index n and assume that the next value must be seen on this or any other thread.

```
Console.WriteLine("Verify");
int[] threadIndexes = new int[nThreads];

for (int counter = 0; counter < GlobalCounter; counter++) 
{
    int nThread = 0;
    for (; nThread < nThreads; nThread++) 
    {
        if (ThreadArrays[nThread][threadIndexes[nThread]]==counter) 
        {
            threadIndexes[nThread]++;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (nThread==nThreads) 
    {
        throw new Exception("Could not find index: " + counter);
    }
}
```

I have renamed the variables to get a more clear naming. I have changed the masked test that the bitmasking is not done in the thread but during verify time which also asserts. This shows that you have a logic problem in your test code. The threaded function does only store the incremented value as in your not masked test.

```
//verify that EVERY index is used exactly by one thread.
Console.WriteLine("Verify");
int[] threadIndexes = new int[nThreads];
int expectedIncrement = 0;
for (int counter = 0; counter < GlobalCounter; counter++) 
{
    int threadIndex = 0;
    for (; threadIndex < nThreads; threadIndex++) 
    {
        if (threadIndexes[threadIndex]<LoopCount && (ThreadArrays[threadIndex][threadIndexes[threadIndex]] & MaxIncrementBitMask)==expectedIncrement) 
        {
            threadIndexes[threadIndex]++;
            expectedIncrement++;
            if (expectedIncrement == MaxIncrementBit)
            {
                expectedIncrement = 0;
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    if (threadIndex==nThreads) 
    {
```

Your check breaks when there is a wraparound in the values. E.g. 0 is the first value. At 0x1000 & 0xFFF it is again 0. Now it can happen that you account some of the wrapped values to the wrong thread and you break the implicit assumption that each thread has only unique values. 
In the debugger I see e.g. for the value 8

```
threadIndexes [0] = 1
threadIndexes [1] = 4
threadIndexes [2] = 0
threadIndexes [3] = 1
threadIndexes [4] = 1
threadIndexes [5] = 1
```

although you must account the first 8 values to threadIndexes[1] which is the first thread which starts counting from 0 to several thousands.

To sum it up: Interlocked and masking works. Your test is flawed and perhaps some of your code relying on invalid assumptions.

Comment: Hi Alois. Finally someone who is actually reading what I wrote. You might be onto something, because when I make "const int maxIncrementModTest = 2*maxThreadIndexIncrementModTest;", which prevents the "%" from masking anything, no error occurs. Thanks for the hint. I need more time to investigate it.

Comment: You are right, my test was wrong. When looking for the next number, it always started to look at thread 0, then 1, 2, until it found the expected number. When mainIndexIncrementTest restarted at 0, there had to come the situation where the correct number would be in a higher thread, but thread zero had by chance the same number. So I wrote a different test which just counts each number mainIndexIncrementTest returned. All occured the same number of times, meaning none was skipped or double used. I accepted your answer.

Comment: Small clarification, `Increment` does not return read value, but altered (i.e. incremented) one.

Answer (score 10):

Rest assured, `Interlocked.Increment` *is* thread-safe. That's its entire purpose!

You are testing that each thread has seen each index exactly once. This would work if the threads were executed one at a time. Say your per-thread count is 10,000:

A would get 0-9999, B would get 10000-19999, etc. -- when masked, each would see 0-9999 exactly once.

But your threads are executing concurrently. So the indexes your threads see are a sporadic, unpredictable interleave:

A gets 0-4999, B gets 5000-9999, A gets 10000-14999, B gets 15000-19999.

Unmasked, each value will remain unique. Masked, A will end up seeing all of 0-4999 twice, and B will see 5000-9999 twice.

You don't state what your end goal is, but a better choice for you might be TLS:

```
[ThreadStatic]
static int perThreadIndex = -1;

int myIndex = ++perThreadIndex;
```

Using the `ThreadStatic` attribute, every thread will only see its own private instance of `perThreadIndex`, so you won't ever need to worry about a thread seeing a duplicate index.

Comment: Your assumption "You are testing that each thread has seen each index exactly once" is COMPLETELY wrong ! If you look at the test code I posted, the test verifies that each number is used only once across all threads. The test is clever enough to detect if the counter returns to 0.

Answer (score 4):

There is no bug.

It is easy to see that the increment is atomic, since it is executed as a single machine instruction, at offset a0 in the second piece of code. Equally, the `and` operation is not atomic since it is executed as a sequence of instructions starting at offset b7.

You can perform an atomic bitwise operation in C++ using the atomic library. You can also implement more complex operations based on atomic compare and exchange. if you are willing to write your code in C++ and call it from C# that would be a solution (Interop works really well).

If you require a C# only solution you can still do it using Interlocked.Exchange. Essentially the strategy is to perform the calculation in a loop until the value you get back on Exchange is the same as the value you used for the calculation, thus guaranteeing no-one else changed it.

And then you can use locks. I never use locks if there is a reasonable alternative.

---

Let me explain atomicity. An operation is atomic if it either executes entirely or not at all, but nothing in between. A single machine instruction is atomic, because instructions are never (visibly) interrupted. Any sequence of instructions is non-atomic because the the sequence could be interrupted. During that interruption in a multi-threaded environment the contents of memory could be changed so as to invalidate the calculation.

There are several strategies to make sequences of instructions atomic in practice, if not in theory.

So, this line of code is atomic, because it generates a single machine instruction.

```
nextIncrement = Interlocked.Increment(ref mainIndexIncrementModTest);

000000a0  inc         dword ptr [ebp-48h]
```

This line of code is not atomic, because it generates many instructions and each instruction executes separately.

```
indexes[testThreadIndex++] = nextIncrement & maskIncrementModTest;

000000b7  mov         eax, dword ptr [ebp-60h] ; <=== load
000000ba  and         eax, 0FFFh               ; <=== &
000000bf  mov         edx, dword ptr [ebp-58h] 
000000c2  mov         ecx, dword ptr [ebp-5Ch] 
000000c5  cmp         edx, dword ptr [ecx+4] 
000000c8  jb          000000CF 
000000ca  call        6DBB208C 
000000cf  mov         dword ptr [ecx+edx*4+8], eax ; <=== store
```

The problem is with the memory load and store. The operation on the AX register is just fine, but loading from and storing to memory relies on those memory values being stable and in a multi-threaded environment that may not be so.

Comment: If I write the code in 2 lines, it is obvious that only the first line must be atomic. nextIncrement is a local variable and cannot be seen by the other threads. But it generates the same error.

              int nextIncrement = Interlocked.Increment(ref mainIndexIncrementModTest);

              indexes[testThreadIndex++] = nextIncrement & maskIncrementModTest;

Comment: An operation is atomic if it generates a single machine instruction. How many lines of code you wrote is immaterial.

Comment: Exactly my point. There is no reason that the "&" operation should give a problem to the other threads, because it operates on the return value of Increment(), which is a local copy. Note that the return value is an Integer, not a reference type.

Comment: The load and store are non-atomic. See edit.

Comment: The "000000af  call        6D947C8B" is the call to Interlocked.Increment(). The compiler does not convert Interlocked.Increment() to "000000a0  inc         dword ptr [ebp-48h]",  because Interlocked.Increment() is doing internally more than just increment. Increment works in the processor's cache. If 2 processors are involved, Interlocked.Increment() must ensure that the latest value is read from RAM (not cache), incremented, written back to RAM. It also needs to return the incremented value. The INC instruction cannot do all that.